# Save error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: String

Tags: apex

On compiling the following snippet, I am getting a 'Save error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: String'. Please let me know what am I missing here! Thanks

```
private Attachment validateAttachment(Attachment attachment){
        String name = attachment.Name;
        String extension = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf('.'), name.length);
        if(acceptedExtension.contains(extension)){
            return attachment;
        }else{
            throw new Exceptions.AppException(); 
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing the parenthesis after `length`.

```java
String extension = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf('.'), name.length());
```

Additionally, the code below will return the dot character too. If you only need the file extension, you can do:

```java
String extension = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1, name.length());
```